# Set Theory notation simplification

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let A and B be sets.

i) Express { $x \mid x ∈ A ∨ x \notin  B$ } as simply as possible in the notation of set theory,
without using set-builder notation.

ii) Express $∀x (x ∈ A ∨ x \notin  B)$ as simply as possible in the notation of set theory,
without any quantiﬁers.

Well for the first part, I get the following: $A-B$

but, I'm confused as to how the other in part two differs? How does the universal quantifier change the meaning?

Comment: The first one is a set, the second one is a logical statement.

Comment: Is it $\{x | x \in A \vee x \notin  B\}$ or $\{x | x \in A \wedge x \notin  B\}$? The former set is not equal to $A \setminus B$.

Comment: @Yury it's exactly as portrayed in the question. Why is not A-B in this case?

Comment: @Dimitri: Then it's equal to $A \cup \bar B$. In particular, every element of $A$ belongs to it: if $a \in A$ then $a\in A \vee a\notin B$ then $a\in \text{your set}$.

Comment: @Yury You're right about that! Ok, so for the second part, where is the difference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I will assume that all elements are restricted to some domain $V$; otherwise, the question doesn't make much sense. We have,
$$\{x| x\in A \vee x\notin B\} = \{x| x\in A \} \cup \{x| x\notin B\} = A \cup (V\setminus B) \equiv A \cup \bar B.$$

2) The formula says that every $x$ either belongs to $A$ or doesn't belong to $B$ (or both). That is, equivalently, there is no $x$ that is not in $A$ and in $B$. We can write that as
$$B\setminus A = \varnothing.$$
Another way to write this is
$$B \subset A.$$

Comment: I'm sure why I'm not seeing this. Did you negate the entire statement?

Comment: Yes, “$∀x (x ∈ A ∨ x \notin  B)$” is equivalent to “$\neg \exists x (x \notin A \wedge x \in  B)$”

Comment: I'm looking at the definition of a proper subset, and is states that a proper subset is a subset which contains fewer elements of its parent set. In this case, how do we now this is so? Shouldn't just simply write it out as $B$ is a subset of $A$ ?

Comment: Different authors use different notation, but usually, $B\subset A$ means that $B$ is a subset of $A$; a proper subset is denoted by $B \subsetneq A$.

Comment: The answer is “$B$ is a subset of $A$”.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is not an exclusion operation. An exclusion operator is:

$$\{x:x\in{A}\land{x}\not\in{B}\}$$

The set in your problem subsumes $A-B$, but it also includes the cases $x\in{A}\land{x}\in{B}$ and $x\not\in{A}\land{x}\not\in{B}$.

The difference between the first and the second problem is that the first one is a description of a set, the second is a statement about two sets.

$$\forall{x}(x\in{A}\lor{x}\not\in{B})$$

means two things: that $B$ is a proper subset of $A$, and that $A$ is a proper subset of the domain of discourse for $x$.